# Change DateTime to Unix timestamp in DataFactory Activity

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory, date-conversion

I am trying to copy Azure tables from one storage account to another storage account. But while doing this copy i want to change a column's datetime value to Unix Timestamp.

I am using Azure DataFactory Copy Activity. If i specify `InitialDate` column type as Int64 in output dataset then i am getting error that `cannot convert datetimeoffset to Int64`.

```
"activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureTableSource"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureTableSink",
                        "azureTablePartitionKeyName": "PartitionKey",
                        "azureTableRowKeyName": "RowKey",
                        "writeBatchSize": 0,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                    },
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": "PartitionKey:PartitionKey,RowKey:RowKey,Timestamp:Timestamp,InitialDate"
                    },
                    "parallelCopies": 32,
                    "cloudDataMovementUnits": 32
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "InputDataset-3tk"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "OutputDataset-3tk"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                    "style": "StartOfInterval",
                    "retry": 3,
                    "longRetry": 0,
                    "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Activity-0-Test->Test"
            }
        ]
```

Is there anyway i can change `InitialDate` column values to `UnixTimestamp (Int64)` while copying to output dataset ?

Are there any other translators other than `TabularTranslator` ? I couldn't find any info in web.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change column value during copy data from one storage table to another storage table with DataFactory. Base on my experience, it is not supported by DataFactory Copy Activity currently.

In my option, there is a workaround is that we could use the [Azure scheduled webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledcronacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-a-cron-expression) to do that. In the WebJob could use [Azure storage SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables)  to copy  table record and the change column value then insert into another table.

Comment: Thanks The table has got more than a billion entities and copy operation takes more than 10 hours. So i would like to use Datafactory's Parallel Copies, DMUs, and monitor features. So WebJobs with Storage SDK is not an option.  Is there anyway i could do it with Custom Activity (IDotNetActivity) ?

Comment: According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities#walkthrough-create-a-custom-activity), it metioned that we could  transform/process data with custom activity.

Comment: Cool. But document didn't mention anything about parallel processing. Though we can specify that property in JSON but not sure how does that work with code logic inside custom activity.

Comment: According to the notes: `*Concurrency** is set to **2** so that two slices are processed in parallel by 2 VMs in the Azure Batch pool`, it seems that  parallel processing it works.